Problema con el Build.gradle
Me han mandado un trabajo en el que tengo que ofuscar código. He elegido una APP que tenía en el móvil y ya no está en la Play Store, pero he conseguido el APK con el APK Extractor. Al pasarla al PC y extraer el contenido, obtengo la carpeta de proyecto. Esa carpeta es la que abro en el Android Studio.
Para ofuscar el código tengo que utilizar Proguard y me han indicado que para activarlo, tengo que incluir esto en el build.gradle:
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled true
             shrinkResources true
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
             'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Pero no me sale la carpeta de Gradles Scripts ¿Alguna solución o idea de por qué no me sale esto en Android Studio?

Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto? ¿En qué etapa del desarrollo ocurre? ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error, si lo hubiera?
